# How can I find out the datatype of measures in MDX?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am new to Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services and MDX.

How can I find out the datatype of measures in MDX?

The measures I am trying to find the datatype for are defined using a WITH clause which as I understand means that it is possible for each measure to have multiple datatypes.

Comment: Please see the link.http://beyondrelational.com/modules/12/tutorials/799/tutorials/17951/getting-started-with-ssas-multidimensional-part-7-creating-measures-in-ssas.aspx

Comment: why do you need the data type? what is the code context of requiring the type? is not knowing the type causing an exception?

Comment: Hi @user2989759 any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

How about the TypeName function:

```
WITH
Member [Measures].[My Type] as
TypeName([Measures].[My Other Measure])
```

Etc...

You are correct that each cell can be a different type of you have a calculations.

Comment: Is this supported by SSAS? I have never come across this function, nor do I see it in BOL.

Comment: It's a VBA function which you can call from MDX

Answer (score 0):

You need to look via `BIDS` or `Visual Studio`.

Use the link provided by @arunbabu :
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/12/tutorials/799/tutorials/17951/getting-started-with-ssas-multidimensional-part-7-creating-measures-in-ssas.aspx

Also long-time scholar on analysis services William Pearson has many helpful articles. Here is one about member properties:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3770686/Intrinsic-Member-Properties-The-MEMBERVALUE-Property.htm

A full catalog of his articles on Database journal is here:
http://www.databasejournal.com/article.php/1459531