# MDX determine if measure is a number or percentage value

Tags: mdx

Is there a way to determine if a measure value is a number or percentage?

I have a calculated member in an excel pivot where is subtracts the previous year value from the current year value to give me the variance.

example of calc:

```
[Product Date].[Fiscal Date].&[1415]-[Product Date].[Fiscal Date].&[1314]
```

What I'd like to do is get the variance percentage and to do this I only need to subtract the previous year value from current when it's a percentage. When the value is a number I need to subtract the previous year value from the current and then divide that by the previous year value.

So is there a way to determine when I need to divide the value or just do the subtraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSAS engine doesn't store percentage values with the `%` operator. In other words, there is no such data type as "percentage".

So, 85% is stored as 0.85 inside the engine.

There is no good way to look at 0.85 and say for sure if it is `85%` or the value `.85`. So, if in your case, the values could be decimals, good luck with that!
BUT, if they are always going to be whole numbers, there is a small hack (which I recently learnt from [GregGalloway's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31168494/2993606)) which can be used.

```
with member measures.MeasureType as
TypeName([Measures].[SomeMeasure])

member measures.ActionTakenOnSomeMeasure as
IIF
 (
  measures.MeasureType = "Double", //Check if the value is double, i.e. Percentage
  [Measures].[SomeMeasure] - ([Date].[Year].currentmember.prevmember, [Measures].[SomeMeasure]),
  ([Measures].[SomeMeasure] - ([Date].[Year].currentmember.prevmember, [Measures].[SomeMeasure]))/([Date].[Year].currentmember.prevmember, [Measures].[SomeMeasure])
 )

select measures.ActionTakenOnSomeMeasure on 0,
[Date].[Year].&[2014]
from [SomeCube]
```

Also there could be case that the values would always be greater than 1 normally. In that case you can simply check the value of the measure additionally in `IIF` clause.